# Using font awesome in a compass project, it works fine for Safari,Chrome & Opera But not for firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox, font-awesome, compass

I'm using Compass to build a Bootsrap-sass & Font-awesome-sass Project and the icons load fine in all browsers but in Firefox.

I get the following error in the console:

```
WARNING: 'fontawesome-webfont.eot' was not found (or cannot be read) in /Users/Scodger/sites/bootstrap-test/fonts/font-awesome
WARNING: 'fontawesome-webfont.eot?' was not found (or cannot be read) in /Users/Scodger/sites/bootstrap-test/fonts/font-awesome
WARNING: 'fontawesome-webfont.woff2' was not found (or cannot be read) in /Users/Scodger/sites/bootstrap-test/fonts/font-awesome
WARNING: 'fontawesome-webfont.woff' was not found (or cannot be read) in /Users/Scodger/sites/bootstrap-test/fonts/font-awesome
WARNING: 'fontawesome-webfont.ttf' was not found (or cannot be read) in /Users/Scodger/sites/bootstrap-test/fonts/font-awesome
WARNING: 'fontawesome-webfont.svg' was not found (or cannot be read) in /Users/Scodger/sites/bootstrap-test/fonts/font-awesome
```

Comment: Can you provide any details where are you loading the font source file from? Adding some of your HTML code will help.

Comment: here is the paths for font-awesome.css @font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url("../fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"), url("../fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("../fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

Comment: This is my main.scss file
*at sign been removed for stackflow*

// Import Bootstrap Compass integration
import "bootstrap-compass";

// Import custom Bootstrap variables
import "bootstrap-variables";

// Import Bootstrap for Sass
import "bootstrap";

import "font-awesome-compass";
import "font-awesome";

Comment: Could you update your question including the troubleshooting code? It looks like you are trying to load the file resources from your disk but you will have to update them with an online available URL so that they can be found by the navigator.

Comment: I Fixed it!! by looking at the code yes your write it was pulling it from a http, so what I done was pulled the source file and copied the fonts and placed them directly into my fonts folder in my project and changing the paths of the fonts. Using compass i Thought it would do this for me locally but I guess not Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by downloading font awesome src files and taking their fonts folder and directly placing them into my project and changing the paths.